# match a route in Compojure / Clout

Tags: regex, clojure

I am trying to match routes of the following form : `{{mongoID}}.{{width}}x{{height}}.{{extension}}`
For instance, `/5591499e2dbc18bd0f000050.240x240.jpeg`is a valid route.

I'd like to be able to destructure it like so :

```
{:id        5591499e2dbc18bd0f000050
 :width     240
 :height    240
 :extension jpeg }
```

`Compojure` supports regex, and dots too apparently https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/issues/42 .

I can have individual regexes for each of the fields, but I'm not sure how to put that into the route path (I'm trying to use the array syntax) :
https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail#matching-the-uri

Let's say I have this :

```
(GET ["/my-route/:mongoID.:widthx:height.:extension" :mongoID ...
                                                     :width ...
                                                     :height  ...
                                                     :extension ...])
```

Obviously the string `"/my-route/:mongoID.:widthx:height.:extension"` won't work (just because the "x" is lost, maybe something else too).

How can I modify my route to make it match my arguments ?

Note : I'm also using Prismatic/Schema if that's useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compojure uses [clout](https://github.com/weavejester/clout) for route matching. That's how it allows you to specify the regex for each parameter. The following works in clout:

```
user=> (require '[clout.core :as clout])
user=> (require '[ring.mock.request :refer [request]])
user=> (clout/route-matches (clout/route-compile "/my-route/:mongoID.:width{\\d+}x:height{\\d+}.:extension") (request :get "/my-route/5591499e2dbc18bd0f000050.240x240.jpeg"))
{:extension "jpeg", :height "240", :width "240", :mongoID "5591499e2dbc18bd0f000050"}
```

So the following should work in compojure:

```
(GET "/my-route/:mongoID.:width{\\d+}x:height{\\d+}.:extension" 
     [mongoID width height extension]
     (do-something-with mongoID width heigth extension)
```

Comment: Well.. I prefer the array syntax but that works. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, the array syntax is better. This might work: `["/my-route/:mongoID.:width:x:height.:extension" :x #"x" :width #"\d+" :height #"\d+" :mongoID #"[^\\.]+"]`. It's a little bit more cumbersome: we need to capture the 'x' as a separate param (which can be ignored when destructuring) and needs a regex for mongoID (instead of the [default](https://github.com/weavejester/clout/blob/master/src/clout/core.clj#L91) of `"[^/,;?]+"`) so it stops at the dot

Comment: That's a good option too; thanks a lot. I can't upvote you anymore but I would :)